# Getting error 'Permission denied (publickey,password)' after 'start-dfs.sh'

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ssh-keys

This question was asked before a few times and I tried all the proposed solutions to generate a passwordless key, but to no avail. May be something different needs to be done as when doing this on Ubuntu from VM Fusion?

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: hadoop@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: hadoop@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [ubuntu]
ubuntu: hadoop@ubuntu: Permission denied (publickey,password).
2021-06-21 22:05:49,215 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Comment: *"I tried all the proposed solutions"* does not tell us anything about what you have actually tried.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you need to have "hadoop" user keys copied on it self on localhost

something like:

```
sudo su hadoop
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id hadoop@localhost
```

then you can try:

```
sudo su hadoop 
ssh hadoop@localhost
```

Comment: Still asking for PW. This is what it showed after: sudo su hadoop.      
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ ssh-copy-id hadoop@localhost
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
hadoop@localhost's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'hadoop@localhost'"
and check ...

Comment: @GhoseBishwajit well, does hadoop still prompt the same error?

Comment: @GhoseBishwajit You need to copy to `hadoop@ubuntu` as well as `localhost`. And make sure in `/etc/hosts` that you don't have a line like `127.0.1.1 ubuntu`